# cant connect to MS SQL server from MYSQL workbench 6.3 CE

Tags: sql-server, mysql-workbench

I am not able to connect to MS SQL database from MYSQL workbench 6.3 CE application.

It throws below error

**Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060**

Is it like MYSQL workbench does not allow to connect to MSSQL server ?

Comment: MSSQL is a completely different protocol. Not sure why you're expecting that to work

Comment: @cricket_007 , i modified port number to 1433 from default 30*** something , I mean , I just assumed it would be able to connect to any DB just for reverse engg purpose, I did not read the complete documentation , I am sorry

Comment: SQL Server uses the TDS, SSTDS, MC-SMP, BINXML,SSCLRT to communicate with clients. I doubt time has been taken to implement reading and writing in those formats in MYSQL workbench.

Answer (score -1):

u can't really connect to a sql server database using workbench.

Found some kind of "hack" there : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-wizard-connection.html

Comment: connection created in migration wizard is not visible in reverse engineering wizard , so the above hack is not successful in my case , do you have any additional pointers please ???

Comment: Migration is exactly that: migrate data from a foreign RDBMS to MySQL (and not a hack of any kind). It has nothing todo with normal DB work.

Comment: @MikeLischke : I understood it off late , thanks anyways